# Alter status Not send email

Tags: magento-1.9

The [Send Email] [Invoice] [Ship] buttons work and send e-mail. Only manual status change that does not send mail

[image: not send email]

Comment: Michael, I have some questions to help clarify your request for everyone. Have you tried any other steps to debug this issue? Was it ever working previously? Is this a production issue? Are you aware of the server's mail system configuration? Do you have the ability/knowledge to test it?

Comment: Rick .. thanks.
The [Send Email] [Invoice] [Ship] buttons work and send e-mail.
Only manual status change that does not send mail.
Outside it all works perfectly
I am a beginner in magento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Michael,

I'm not exactly sure of your problem, but I'll walk you through these systems in Magento as a beginner to help you find the solution on your own.

---

## TL;DR

- Ensure `crontab` is running + the task scheduler is setup
- Consult the `core_email_queue` table to verify your email was generated
- Trace the call stack on `core/email_queue::send` to confirm send success

---

Long description below ...

#### Order Comment Request Processing

When you click the <kbd>Add Comment</kbd> button, you are posting the comment to this file:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/controllers/Adminhtml/OrderController.php
```

In this class, its `addCommentsAction` method is being called.

> ⓘ See http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-3.html for more information on controllers.

Depending on your version, see around line `285`, for this call:

```
$order->sendOrderUpdateEmail($notify, $comment);
```

You need to know that `$order` is an instance of `Mage_Sales_Model_Order`, the corresponding class which can be found here:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php
```

So if you inspect that class, find its `sendOrderUpdateEmail` method. It will show you how it simply wraps the call to a sibling method, `queueOrderUpdateEmail`.

#### Email Queue System

Since Magento CE 1.9.1.0, a mail queue was introduced to *defer* sending of mail until a later time. It requires that the Magento task scheduler system is working, and that system is usually dependent on the host `crontab` service.

> ⓘ See http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installing_install.html#install-cron to make sure your task scheduler is working.

If that was working as expected, you can go a little deeper from where we left off in the last section. Review the `queueOrderUpdateEmail` method on the order model, paying close attention around line `1452`:

```
$mailer->setQueue($emailQueue)->send();
```

In the middle of the `$mailer` model we are injecting `$emailQueue` before "sending" the email. By injecting a queue, we are requesting that Magento does not send the email immediately, but store it in the database until the task scheduler picks it up a little later.

The `$mailer` object is an instance of `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer`, and its corresponding class is here:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Mailer.php
```

> ⓘ Beginner's tip: do you see the pattern in the class name and the file path? This is the secret to Magento's autoloader. Here's a decent article to get your feet wet with it: http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2015/05/17/magento-autoloader-and-compilation-process/

So this class's `send` method will be called, and if you study ~lines `75-84` you will see another call out to `$emailTemplate`, the "email template processor model." This model takes our email template and generates HTML output (the final email content). The corresponding class is `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template`, and the file is found here:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php
```

We're getting closer. Study its `sendTransactional` method, which ultimately points to the sibling `send` method. It is in **this method** where we see the queue at work. Lines `407-426` demonstrate how Magento, upon detecting that we passed in a queue object, will take the generated email content and write it to the database as a record to process later.

> ⓘ Advanced tip: the database table here is `core_email_queue`. The only way to know that is to understand how Magento model's connect to the database. For more information read here: http://alanstorm.com/magento_models_orm/

If you check the table holding these queue records, `core_email_queue`, you should find your email bound for the recipient sitting in there.

The queue is configured to be processed every minute. So long as your task scheduler is working properly, you can expect that this queue record would be processed shortly after it went into the table. This table maintains the time at which the emails are processed. See the `processed_at` column of the table to confirm.

#### Final Thoughts

I've only walked you through the process of how Magento sends order update emails. It's up to you to do some research at each of these steps along the way to confirm that information is being sent as it should.

If you studied the context of the code I referenced, you might have noticed that when adding a comment, the "Notified ✔" status is saved to the comment **before** the email is actually sent. This is misleading, because you think the status indicates a successful mail send, yet it only means you *elected* to notify the customer.

Examining the mail queue in the database is probably your best bet to diagnose this.

Comment: I was able to find by checking the places you mentioned.

I changed
[ $mailer->setQueue($emailQueue)->send(); ]
to
[ $Mailer->send(); ].

And the email was sent.

I looked in the database where you mentioned and the emails are really getting stuck in the bank.

I believe I need to configure Cron.

that's right

Comment: I'm sorry, my bad English. I hope you understood.

Comment: I managed to solve it, I disabled cron myself! Was giving api problem with different versions.

Thank for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that editing the core to remove the queue is discouraged, for a test/dev environment you should be OK. Magento uses a queue in order to reduce the chances for transaction failure, like with order placement during checkout.